# Which Jekyll plugins are whitelisted by GitHub Pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I heard somewhere that GitHub pages support a *small* number of white-listed Jekyll plugins, yet I can't seem to find a comprehensive list anywhere.

Where can this information be found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a list with the Jekyll plugins that GitHub Pages support:

https://pages.github.com/versions/

Answer (score 4):

I’d like to add that the link *Red* provided may be outdated when more plugins get whitelisted.

[github/pages-gem: plugins.rb](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/master/lib/github-pages/plugins.rb#L21-L42) should be up to date.

Comment: I think the list itself slightly shifted to a subfolder:
[github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/master/lib/github-pages/plugins.rb](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/master/lib/github-pages/plugins.rb)